# how to return a list of students

Tags: c#

there is my method that return a student from the database with his name,
i want to modify my method to return a list of students if i have many students with the same name, how can i do, thanks

```
    // GET: api/Students/name
    [ResponseType(typeof(Student))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetStudentByName(string Name)
    {

        Student student = db.Students.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == Name);

        if (student == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(student);
    }
```

Comment: Change `db.Students.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == Name)` to `db.Students.Where(t => t.Name == Name)` and `ResponseType` you don't need I suppose or it needs to be `List<Student>`

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try? What do you need help with?

Answer (score 3):

**For Reference**

[Enumerable.Where Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

[Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no
>   element is found.

Also note you need to change your `ResponseType` to `List<Student>`

**Example**

```
[ResponseType(typeof(List<Student>))]
public IHttpActionResult GetStudentByName(string Name)
{
    var students = db.Students.Where(t => t.Name == Name).ToList();

    if (!students.any())
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(students);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Student> student = db.Students.Where(t => t.Name == Name).ToList()
```

Comment: No Porblem :)))

Comment: And if i want to return just the name of students, not the hole student, how can i do ?

Comment: List<Student> student = db.Students.Where(t => t.Name == Name).Select(s => s.Name).ToList()

Answer (score -1):

```
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Student>))]
public IHttpActionResult GetStudentsByName(string Name)
{    
    var students = db.Students.Where(t => t.Name == Name).ToList();

    return students.Count == 0 ? NotFound() : Ok(students);
}
```